# Having a problem updating a database and getting no errors

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

I am trying to allow a user to update their account information.

I have a myaccount page which has a form. The form is prepopulated with the current information in the database for their account. My Select statement works, gets their info and populates.

I then check if any values have changed on form submit button press. If the field has changed i create an update statement with the changed values.

I am getting no errors when i run it but it is not updating the database

here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once(__DIR__ . '/square-connect/autoload.php');
$passcheck;
$formerrormsg;
// Configure Square Authorization
$accesstoken = '***************';
SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($accesstoken);
$customer_api = new SquareConnect\Api\CustomersApi();
$body = new \SquareConnect\Model\UpdateCustomerRequest();
// redirect user to login page if they're not logged in
if (!isset($_SESSION['Customer']) || empty($_SESSION['Customer'])) {
    header('location: login.php');
} else {
    $id = $_SESSION['Customer']['id'];
    $location = "sql300.epizy.com";
    $user = "epiz_23758113";
    $dbpass = "*************";
    $database = "epiz_23758113_Customers";
    $link = new mysqli($location, $user, $dbpass, $database);
    // Check connection
    if ($link->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Customerid = '$id'";
    $customer_result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($customer_result)){
        $first_name = $row[1];
        $last_name = $row[2];
        $email = $row[3];
        $password = $row[4];
        $phone = $row[5];
        $address = $row[6];
        $apt = $row[7];
        $city = $row[8];
        $province = $row[9];
        $postalcode = $row[10];
        $country = $row[11];
        $verified = $row[12];
    };
    mysqli_free_result($customer_result);
    //UPDATING ACCOUNT
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //check passwords match
        if($_POST["contact_form_pass1"] != $_POST["contact_form_pass2"] || $_POST["contact_form_pass1"] = "......." || $_POST["contact_form_pass2"] = "......." ){
            $passcheck = 1;
            if (empty($formerrormsg)){
                $formerrormsg = "Passwords Do Not MATCH or were not changed";
            } else {
                $formerrormsg = $formerrormsg . "<br/> Passwords Do Not MATCH or were not changed";
            }
        }else{
            //CHECK DATABASE FOR ALREADY MATCHING EMAIL
            if (!isset($passcheck)){
                //check password meets critera
                if(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_-]{6,18}$/', $_POST["contact_form_pass1"])){
                    $check = 1;
                    if (empty($formerrormsg)){
                        $formerrormsg = "Password must be 6-18 Characters and must only be letters, number, - or _";
                    } else {
                        $formerrormsg = $formerrormsg . "<br/> Password must be 6-18 Characters and must only be letters, number, - or _";
                    }
                }
                $first_name2 = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['contact_form_first-name']);
                $last_name2 = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['contact_form_last-name']);
                $phone2 = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['contact_form_phone']);
                $email2 = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['contact_form_email']);
                $passinput = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['contact_form_pass1']);
                $passinputchk = password_verify($passinput, $password);
                $address2 = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['contact_form_st-address']);;
                $apt2 = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['contact_form_apt']);
                $province2 = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['contact_form_province']);
                $postalcode2 = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['contact_form_PostalCode']);
                $city2 = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['contact_form_city']);
                $addressarray= array();
                $update_query;
                $update_query1 = "UPDATE accounts SET ";
                $update_query2;
                $update_query3 = " WHERE 'CustomerId'=$id";
                if ($first_name2 != $first_name){
                    $body->setGivenName($first_name2);
                    $update_query2 = $update_query2 . "'FirstName'=$first_name2";
                }
                if ($last_name2 != $last_name){
                    $body->setFamilyName($last_name2);
                    if(isset($update_query2)){
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . ",'LastName'=$last_name2";
                    } else {
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . "'LastName'=$last_name2";
                    }
                }
                if ($email2 != $email){
                    $body->setEmailAddress($email2);
                    $verified2 = 0;
                    if(isset($update_query2)){
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . ",'Email'=$email2";
                    } else {
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . "'Email'=$email2";
                    }
                }
                if (password_verify($passinput, $password)){

                } else {
                    $password = password_hash($passinput, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    if(isset($update_query2)){
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . ",'password'=$password";
                    } else {
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . "'password'=$password";
                    }
                }
                if ($phone2 != $phone){
                    $body->setPhoneNumber($phone);
                    if(isset($update_query2)){
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . ",'Phone'=$phone2";
                    } else {
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . "'Phone'=$phone2";
                    }
                }
                if ($address2 != $address){
                    if(isset($addressarray)){
                        array_push($addressarray, ",'address_line_1'=>$address2");
                    } else {
                        array_push($addressarray, "'address_line_1'=>$address2");
                    }
                    if(isset($update_query2)){
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . ",'Address'=$address2";
                    } else {
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . "'Address'=$address2";
                    }
                }
                if ($apt2 != $apt){
                    if(isset($addressarray)){
                        array_push($addressarray, ",'address_line_2'=>$apt2");
                    } else {
                        array_push($addressarray, "'address_line_2'=>$apt2");
                    }
                    if(isset($update_query2)){
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . ",'apt'=$apt2";
                    } else {
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . "'apt'=$apt2";
                    }
                }
                if ($city2 != $city){
                    if(isset($addressarray)){
                        array_push($addressarray, ",'locality'=>$city2");
                    } else {
                        array_push($addressarray, "'locality'=>$city2");
                    }
                    if(isset($update_query2)){
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . ",'City'=$city2";
                    } else {
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . "'City'=$city2";
                    }
                }
                if ($province2 != $province){
                    if(isset($addressarray)){
                        array_push($addressarray, ",'administrative_district_level_1'=>$province2");
                    } else {
                        array_push($addressarray, "'administrative_district_level_1'=>$province2");
                    }
                    if(isset($update_query2)){
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . ",'Province'=$province2";
                    } else {
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . "'Province'=$province2";
                    }
                }
                if ($postalcode2 != $postalcode){
                    if(isset($addressarray)){
                        array_push($addressarray, "',postal_code'=>$postalcode2");
                    } else {
                        array_push($addressarray, "'postal_code'=>$postalcode2");
                    }
                    if(isset($update_query2)){
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . ",'PostalCode'=$postalcode2";
                    } else {
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . "'PostalCode'=$postalcode2";
                    }
                }
                if (isset($verified2)){
                    if(isset($update_query2)){
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . ",'verified'=$verified2";
                    } else {
                        $update_query2 = $update_query2 . "'verified'=$verified2";
                    }
                }
                if(isset($addressarray)){
                    $body->setAddress($addressarray);
                }
                if(isset($update_query2)){
                    $update_query = "$update_query1" . "$update_query2" . "$update_query3"; 
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$update_query');</script>";
                    try {
                        //DOES NOT EXIST IN DB SO INSERT IT
                        $customer_insert = mysqli_query($link, $update_query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
                        $link->close();
                        //Update SQUARE
                        $customerresult = $customer_api->UpdateCustomerRequest($id,$body);
                        if(isset($first_name2)){
                            $first_name=$first_name2;
                        }
                        if(isset($last_name2)){
                            $last_name=$last_name2;    
                        }
                        $customersession = array
                                (
                                'id'=>$id,
                                'firstname'=>$first_name,
                                'lastname'=>$last_name,
                                'pass'=>$password
                            );
                        $_SESSION["Customer"] = $customersession;
                        mysqli_free_result($customer_insert);
                        //header('Location: myaccount.php');
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo 'Exception when calling CustomersApi->updateCustomer: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("No Changes Made");</script>';
                }

            }
        }
    }
    $link->close();
    ?>
```

I am trying to take only changed inputs, then put them in a variable.
I use 3 variables first is the first part of the UPDATE statement, second is for the values i want to update and 3rd is for the WHERE clause, i then concatenate together to form 1. i pass that to a mysqli_query.

Ideally i want this to update my database with the changed values.

Answer (score 0):

My request, While posting the codes on other sites please avoid putting your configuration details.

1. Check error mode is enabled
2. print $update_query statement and and check with mysql.

Comment: Error mode is enabled in php settings. What do you mean check with sql? When I go into my tables after trying to run an update nothing is changed if that is what you mean?

Comment: I meant, execute the generated update query directly on your Mysql interface.